# scikit-image radon transform alteration

Tags: python, image, transform, scikit-image

I'm trying to use the scikit-image radon transform function in Python which can be found at:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/radon_transform.py

I'm trying to alter the formula behind-the-scenes such that it calculates the integral:

[image]

Rather than the standard:

[image]

But I can't seem to find the code where the integration is explicitly carried out.

As this function is working with pixels, perhaps it is calculating the integral as a summation, having already identified the pixels  through which the line L goes through?

I've tried altering the last line of code:

```
radon_image[:, i] = rotated.sum(0)
```

to

```
radon_image[:, i] = rotated.sum(0) - rotated.mean()
```

in the function: scikit-image/skimage/transform/radon_transform.py/radon.

But it doesn't have an affect and this code seems so heavily optimised that I can't see where to add my changes.

Many thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Comment: I think you are modifying the correct code, but make sure that you are changing the *installed* version on your system.  Typically, when you work on a package, you check out the source code, run `pip install -e .` (editable install), and then modify the package in-place.  Good luck!

Comment: I've used all the original functions in the package bar the radon() function which I've copied and modified in an IDE before calling. Doesn't seem to make the difference that I'd hope to find but I'll keep digging.